# how to make a folder with the same name as a file in command prompt (Recurse subfolders)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, batch

Ok I have like 15,000+ files I need to do this to.
I tried this 
my root directory is `C:\asf>`
the command is: `for /r %x in (*.asf) do aifdump -hr "%x" "%CD%"`

but the files are going to my root directory and are being overwritten
the syntax for aifdump is aifdump.exe [Option] [ASF_path] [Texture_dump_path]
any method to fix this problem is ok even if you use python or similar thank you for your help

here is a sample if you need it to work with: http://www.mediafire.com/?e9jwa3tkedilcy5

thank you for your help Michael and Bob. when i run the command it does this

`C:\asf>for /r %x in (*.asf) do aifdump -hr "%x" "%~dpnx"`

`C:\asf>aifdump -hr "C:\asf\9\0.asf" "C:\asf\9\0"`

`Texture 0.dds : 2.00 KB`

and then aifdump will crash. i found out that if i make the output folder before

running the command it will work so how would i rework the command to make

the directories needed before running the command for aifdump.

I figured it out i just had to change `aifdump -hr` to `mkdir`

again thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%CD%` is always going to return the directory that you was current when you ran the command; in this case that's `C:\asf`'. If I interpret what you're asking, you want each of them to go into a separate directory? If so you just need to build that directory name in your command.

Note, howeve,r that you *cannot* have a file and a folder with the same name and same parent path; for example, if you had a file named `C:\asdf\asdf.asf`, you *cannot* also make a folder named `C:\asdf\asdf.asf` because the path would be ambiguous.

The easiest option would be to strip off the file extension, which the `for` command can do for you:

```
for /r %x in (*.asf) do aifdump -hr "%x" "%~dpnx"
```

NOTE: `%~dpnx` is a concatenation of three modifiers, and gives the drive, path, and name (without extension) of the file name contained in the variable x.

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess you want the output path to be in the same place as the source file?

```
for /r %x in (*.asf) do aifdump -hr "%x" "%~dpx"
```

The `%~` is a special modifier, see `for /?`. If `%x` is `C:\asf\blah\bleh\file.asf`: `dp` indicates drive (`C:`) and path (`\asf\blah\bleh\`), making `C:\asf\blah\bleh\`.